# how to read file with struct in cpp

Tags: c++

I have code

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <fstream>
        using namespace std;

        struct triangle
        {
            float x;
            float y;
        };

        int main() {
            float x, y;

            struct triangle triangles[100];

            ofstream theFile("toado.txt");

            for(int index = 0; index < 3 ; index ++) {
                cout<<"please enter the coordinates x,y of point in of triangle : "<<endl;
                cin>>x>>y;
                theFile <<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
            }

             int i=0;

             ifstream fileRead("toado.txt");
             while(fileRead >> triangles[i].x >> triangles[i].y) {
                i++; 
             }
             cout<<"====================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
             for (int index = 0; index < i; index ++) {
                cout<<"the coordinates x, y of point "<<index+1<<" : ("<<triangles[i].x<<","<<triangles[i].x<<")"<<endl;
             }
             cout<<"====================================================================="<<endl<<endl;
            return 0;       
        }
```

when I entered value : 1 2, 3 4, 5 6
but output same as below

> (-3.97922e-15,-3.97922e-15)  (-3.97922e-15,-3.97922e-15) (-3.97922e-15,-3.97922e-15)

Comment: Are you sure the file was opened successfully?

Comment: Personally, I prefer good old [fread()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)

Comment: yes, my file was opened successfully, I'm sure!

Comment: But it was not `close`d properly, before constructing `fileRead`.

Comment: It doesn't help that you print x twice instead x and y on your "the coordinates" line.

Comment: I added theFile.close(); but it did not work

Comment: @Tiến Dũng - please "accept" kfsone's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is very simple

```
cout<<"the coordinates x, y of point "<<index+1<<" : ("<<triangles[i].x<<","<<triangles[i].x<<")"<<endl;
```

should be

```
cout<<"the coordinates x, y of point "<<index+1<<" : ("<<triangles[index].x<<","<<triangles[index].y<<")"<<endl;
```

that is

```
triangles[  i  ].x  =>   triangles[  index  ].x
```

and you were printing `x` both times, so I fixed the second `x` to a `y`.